# Convert Dynamic IP address to string

Tags: bash, pyspark, anaconda, ip

I need to convert a `dynamic IP address` to a `string` in order to add it to my `spark` **conf** within the **kernel.json**.

Here my kernel.json:

```
{
  "argv": [
    "/opt/conda/bin/python3",
    "-m",
    "ipykernel_launcher",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "display_name": "python",
  "language": "python",
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/spark",
  "JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64",
  "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON": "/opt/conda/bin/python3",
  "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3",
  "PYLIB":"/usr/local/spark/python/lib",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/spark/python/:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master spark://spark-master-svc.xxxxx.svc.cluster.local:7077 --conf spark.driver.host=**IP** --conf spark.driver.port='8888' --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=**IP** pyspark-shell"
 }
 
}
```

I tried to replace ****IP**** with `$(hostname -i)` but not working because what is inside `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` is seen as a string.

Any solution please?

And please be clear with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i "s/\*\*IP\*\*/$(hostname -i)/g" kernel.json
```

- you have to put `\` before every `*`
- use double quotes so `$(hostname -i)` is executed.
- the operation you want to use for `sed` is `s/WHAT-TO-REPLACE/REPLACE-BY-WHAT/g`.
- The `g` option will ensure that every instance of `**IP**` will be replaced in each line.